# VB.NET sort IEnumerable class

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, sorting, ienumerable

I want to sort a VB class that implements IEnumerable.
I don't want a new object / linq.
It must stay as the original object but sorted.
Here is a sample class.

```
Public Class Person
    Public Sub New(ByVal fName As String, ByVal lName As String)
        Me.firstName = fName
        Me.lastName = lName
    End Sub

    Public firstName As String
    Public lastName As String
End Class

Public Class People
    Implements IEnumerable(Of Person)

    Private _people() As Person

    Public Sub New(ByVal pArray() As Person)
        _people = New Person(pArray.Length - 1) {}

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To pArray.Length - 1
            _people(i) = pArray(i)
        Next i
    End Sub

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of Person) _
            Implements IEnumerable(Of Person).GetEnumerator
        Return DirectCast(_people, IEnumerable(Of Person)).GetEnumerator
    End Function

    Private Function System_Collections_GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator _
            Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return Me.GetEnumerator
    End Function
End Class
```

I know I can use LINQ but then I get a new object not the original sorted.
There are too many places that use the global "peopleList" object so I need to sort the "peopleList" not a new sorted list of "People".

```
Dim peopleList As New People({ _
    New Person("John", "Smith"), _
    New Person("Jim", "Johnson"), _
    New Person("Sue", "Rabon")})
Dim newPeopleList = From person In peopleList Order By person.firstName Select person
'OR
Dim newPeopleList = DirectCast(peopleList, IEnumerable(Of Person)).ToList()
newPeopleList.Sort(Function(p1, p2) p1.firstName.CompareTo(p2.firstName))
```

I need something more like the following.

```
Dim peopleList As New People({ _
    New Person("John", "Smith"), _
    New Person("Jim", "Johnson"), _
    New Person("Sue", "Rabon")})
peopleList = peopleList.Sort(Function(p) p.firstName)
```

I know IEnumerable does not have a Sort method. I am only showing it as an example.
I do have the option to modify the "People" class but in the end it must still implement IEnumerable because I don't want to break the current callers.
Also the current callers must be able to see the "peopleList" sorted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort the `Person` objects as you're creating the `People` list:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal pArray() As Person)
    _people = New Person(pArray.Length - 1) {}

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For
    For Each person In pArray.OrderBy(Function(p) p.firstName)
        _people(i) = person
        i = i + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can provide your own method to sort the internal array after it has been created. Something like this should work:

```
Public Class People
    Public Sub Sort(Of T As IComparable)(KeySelector As Func(Of Person, T))
        Array.Sort(_people, Function(x, y) KeySelector(x).CompareTo(KeySelector(y)))
    End Sub
End Class
```

And you can call the like like this:

```
peopleList.Sort(Function(p) p.firstName)
```

Comment: That is one option but some other method populated the object before I queried the object. So a "Sort" method / functionality of some sort would be much nicer to have. Something like this http://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/sort-ienumerable-and-list-with-property-name/ but in VB.

Comment: I do like the updated answer but it does not compile on my machine using .NET 3.5... the line Func(Person, T) -- "Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers"

Comment: @goroth Oops, my mistake; my VB.NET is a little rusty. See my updated answer.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. It's a shame that no one has a VB.NET extension method to do what you have listed. I have several classes that implement IEnumerable and it would be nice if I did not have to edit each of them but I didn't say I needed an extension method in the post so you did give me what I asked for.

Comment: @goroth Well you can just use Linq's `.OrderBy` extension method (which I used in the first example), but that will always return a new `IEnumerable`, and can't be used to modify an existing object.

Comment: I'm going to keep digging to see if anyone has an VB.NET extension method to do this and I will post if I ever find it. Anyway I accept your answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could just sort the underlying array and use a custom IComparer to suit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzw8611x.aspx

Something like:

```
public class PersonComparer: IComparer<Person>
{
    public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {            
        return x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName);
    }
}
```

And then in your People class:

```
public sub Sort()

     PersonComparer pc = new PersonComparer()

    Array.Sort(_people, pc)

end sub
```

Comment: I have already been down this path but never figured out how to sort by other properties besides FirstName. Such as LastName.

Comment: Well, if you can make it work for `FirstName`, that indicates you're on the right path. Maybe you should ask a separate question for how you could make the comparer use multiple fields (but really: before you ask that, try to work out the logic on a piece of paper. It's not complex!).

Comment: p.s.w.g's answer seems like a good way of implementing what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a `Sort` method:

```
Public Sub Sort()
    _people = _people.OrderBy(Function(p) p.firstname).ToArray()
End Sub

Public Sub Sort(Of TKey)(keySelector As Func(Of Person, TKey))
    _people = _people.OrderBy(keySelector).ToArray()
End Sub
```

Or sort when you return the enumerator:

```
Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of Person) _
        Implements IEnumerable(Of Person).GetEnumerator
    Return _people.OrderBy(Function(p) p.firstname).GetEnumerator()
End Function
```